# (De)serializing child JSON attributes into class properties

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, .net-5

Let's say I have a controller which accepts the following JSON:

```json
{
    "propA": "val1",
    "propB": {
        "propC": "val2",
        "propD": "val3"
    },
    "propE": "val4"
}
```

Without using a custom `JsonConverter`, is there a way to deserialize this JSON into a class such as:

```cs
public record Payload(
    string PropA,
    string PropC,
    string PropD,
    string PropE
);
```

The JSON object "PropB" should be unwrapped, and the two child attributes "PropC" and "PropD" mapped directly to the corresponding properties of the class.

I'm using the built-in JSON classes from `System.Text`.

Comment: "*Without using a custom serializer*" define "*custom serializer*"

Comment: without a custom _de_-serializer, you mean? no. but if i might ask: _why_ are you even accepting JSON in this format?

Comment: @00110001, I meant a custom `JsonConverter`.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann, I'm working within the constraints of an existing legacy system. If there's a way to do without, that would be ideal.

Comment: @metacubed i think a custom deserializer might be _the_ way to go. after all, isn't that exactly the use case they were made for? what exactly is the problem with creating one? (also, when that's _completely_ out of the question, create an intermediate DTO and use an automapper)

Comment: @FranzGleichmann, yeah, that might turn out to be the case. I'm checking whether there's a built-in attribute which performs the unwrapping out of the box.

Comment: @metacubed Have you considered to use `JsonElement.Parse` to have a semi-parsed data? Then you can retrieve the desired element via the`GetProperty` [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement.getproperty)

Comment: `"propE", "valE"` - that's a typo, right?

Comment: @Fildor, corrected

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom `JsonConverter`. Parse `JsonString` to `JsonObject` by using **Newtonsoft** and set Class property value by **Reflection** with its name.

**Model**

```
public class Payload {
    public string propA { get; set; }
    public string propC { get; set; }
    public string propD { get; set; }
    public string propE { get; set; }
}
```

**Converter**

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

    ...

    string strJSON = "{\"propA\": \"val1\",\"propB\": {\"propC\": \"val2\",\"propD\": \"val3\"},\"propE\": \"val4\"}";
    JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(strJSON);

    Payload payload = new Payload();
    foreach (JProperty property in jsonObject.Properties())
    {
        if (property.Value != null && payload.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name) != null)
            payload.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).SetValue(payload, property.Value.ToString());
        else
        {
            JObject obj = (JObject)property.Value;
            foreach (JProperty prop in obj.Properties())
            {
                if (prop.Value != null)
                    payload.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).SetValue(payload, prop.Value.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("payload.propA : " + payload.propA);
    Console.WriteLine("payload.propC : " + payload.propC);
    Console.WriteLine("payload.propD : " + payload.propD);
    Console.WriteLine("payload.propE : " + payload.propE);
```

Results:

[image]